# In Python, why is my for-loop excluding the number before a specific number only when that number is the last in the array?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am working on a codingbat problem, and I am getting unexpected results when the excluded number is at the end of the array.

```
def sum13(nums):
  a = []

  if len(nums) == 0:
    return 0
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == 13 or nums[i-1] == 13:
      continue
    a.append(nums[i])

  return sum(a)
```

The code should append all numbers in the array to list a and return the sum, excluding any instances of the number 13 and the number immediately following it. It works fine for most of the tests, but when the array ends in 13, it doesn't append the number at index 0 to the list, returning the wrong result.

Comment: What do you think happens when `i=0`, what is `nums[-1]`? It's the last element. Here's your problem.

Comment: A small semantics point, but I think `if not nums` is more pythonic than `if len(nums) ==0` or `if not len(nums)`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow- if i = 0, then that would be the first element. nums[0-1] would yield nums[-1], but that should just check to see if the last item in the list equalled 13; it shouldn't cancel out the element before it?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `i` is 0, `nums[-1]` is evaluated. `nums[-1]` is the last element of `nums`. Therein lies your problem.

If `nums[-1]` is 13, `continue` is executed, so nothing is appended to `nums`

Comment: Why does it append `nums[-1]`? The code is `a.append(nums[i])`.

Comment: But the symptom is different from what he says. It leaves out the first element when the last element is 13.

Comment: if the last element is 13, the `continue` is executed, so nothing is appended

Comment: He's corrected the question, now the error he describes matches this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is using list indices a must? You can just simply iterate through the list and set a flag once you find a 13, and reset it once you pass that next number.